# Getting an element to able to be clicked after addClass("disabled")

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Problem #2 (Unresolved, need help)

Last updated: 2:20 p.m. EST

In the case of ethnicity (see `scripts.js`), I'm looking to have users be able to select two items before things are unable to be selected. For example, they could click `<p class="rect E1">White</p>` and `<p class="rect E2">Black</p>`

#### How would I go about doing this?

---

### Update to Problem #1:

I've made it so that clicking `<p class="rect G1">Male</p>` located in my `index.html` will add a class of `.disabled` (see my `chart.scss`) to the option "Female" `<p class="rect G2">Female</p>` making it unclickable.

I want the user be able to be able to click the option for Female, only if the Male option is clicked a second time to be "unselected." I've tried to .removeClass(".disabled"), but that hasn't worked.

## Solution

```
$(".G2).toggleClass("disabled")
```

### index.html

```
<section class="selection">
                <div class="gender">
                    <p class="category">Gender</p>
                    <div class="options">
                        <p class="rect G1">Male</p>
                        <p class="rect G2">Female</p>
                    </div><!-- /.options -->
                </div><!-- /.gender -->

                <div class="age">
                    <p class="category">Age</p>
                    <div class="options">
                        <p class="rect A1">Under 35</p>
                        <p class="rect A2">36-64</p>
                        <p class="rect A3">65+</p>
                    </div><!-- /.options -->
                </div><!-- /.age -->

                <div class="ethnicity">
                    <p class="category">Ethnicity<span>*<span></p>
                    <div class="options">
                        <p class="rect E1">White</p>
                        <p class="rect E2">Black</p>
                        <p class="rect E3">Aboriginal</p>
                        <p class="rect E4">Metis</p>
                        <p class="rect E5">Asian</p>
                    </div><!-- /.options -->
                </div><!-- /.ethnicity -->
            </section>

                <img src="assets/img/headshots/allan.jpg" alt="" class="headshot NDP Female White">
                <img src="assets/img/headshots/allum.jpg" alt="" class="headshot NDP Male White">
                <img src="assets/img/headshots/altemeyer.jpg" alt="" class="headshot NDP Male White">
```

### scripts.js

```
    $(function() {

        // Numbers
        var total = 56
        var male = 41;
        var female = 15;

        // Option #1: Gender
    $( ".G1" ).click(function() {
        $(".G2").addClass("disabled");
        $(".headshot").not(".Female").toggleClass("opacity");
        // $(".G2").removeClass("disabled");
        $(".number").html(total - female);
    });

    $( ".G2" ).click(function() {
        $(".G1").addClass("disabled");
        $(".headshot").not(".Male").toggleClass("opacity");
        $(".number").html(total - male);
    });
});
```

### chart.scss

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Why cant you just use radio buttons?

Comment: Try this

$(".G2").toggleClass("disabled");

Comment: @saisudhakar That was correct .toggleClass("disabled") worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Problem #2: Sounds like you should be using checkboxes instead.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="White" />White<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="Black" />Black<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="Aboriginal" />Aboriginal<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="Metis" />Metis<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="Asian" />Asian<br />

$("input[name='chk_group']").on("change", function() {
    var $checkedChxBx = $("input[name='chk_group']:checked");

    if($checkedChxBx.length >= 2)
    {
        var $uncheckedChxbx = $("input[name='chk_group']:not(:checked)");
        $.each($uncheckedChxbx,function() {
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $("input[name='chk_group']").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

I created a Fiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/bq9qgmsd/

Comment: Is it possible to style a checkbox so that the text is clickable and the box doesn't show up, but it's still technically and input.

Comment: You can use use hyperlinks or paragraphs too. Instead of using the 'name' attribute, give them all a common css class so you can use jquery to select them as a group. Then you can toggle your custom "disabled" css class. Please mark the answer if this resolves your issue or leads you to a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to removing the disabled class, you need to specifically re-enable the pointer events by creating an enabled class and adding it to the element:

```
.enabled {
    pointer-events: all;
}
```